# PostgreSQL IP pool

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got the following function to get a free IP address from a pool:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ip(inp_id CHARACTER(9)) RETURNS INET AS $$
    DECLARE ip_assigned INET;
    BEGIN
        ip_assigned := (COALESCE((SELECT ip FROM ips WHERE id = inp_id),
                                 (SELECT (a.ip + 1) AS ip
                                  FROM ips a LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM ips b WHERE a.ip < b.ip ORDER BY b.ip ASC LIMIT 1) AS q ON true
                                  WHERE q.ip <> (a.ip + 1)
                                  ORDER BY ip ASC LIMIT 1)));

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ips WHERE id = inp_id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ips WHERE ip = ip_assigned) THEN
            INSERT INTO ips VALUES (ip_assigned, inp_id);
            RETURN ip_assigned;
        ELSEIF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ips WHERE id = inp_id AND ip = ip_assigned) THEN
            RETURN ip_assigned;
        ELSE
            RETURN '0.0.0.0';
        END IF;

    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It seems to work, but I'm unsure if there could be any need for locking the table when retreiving IP and inserting into the table.

I'm checking if the IP exists already, and if the id requiring and IP has an address.
`0.0.0.0` is returned if something fails.

`inp_id` is the client requesting an `IP`, and the `ips` table has 2 columns; `ip` and `id`, for matching client ID and IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function seems very complicated, and I am not convinced that it is doing its job at all.

It won't work if `ips` is empty, and you'll never get an address lower than the lowest address in the table, so you'd have to make sure that this lowest address is never deleted from the table.

Anyway, to your question:

I guess that you want to avoid that the same address is returned to concurrent callers of the function.

For that, it would be enough to create a `UNIQUE` constraint on `ips` that forbids adding the same IP address twice.

Then you should catch that error during `INSERT` and retry the whole operation in case of error.

Here is my version of your function.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ips(
   ip inet UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   id character(9) PRIMARY KEY 
);  

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ip(inp_id character(9)) RETURNS inet
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$$DECLARE
   min_ip inet := '192.168.0.0';
   max_ip inet := '192.168.255.255';
   new_ip inet;
BEGIN
   /* loop until we find and can insert a new address */
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         /* don't do anything if the entry already exists */
         SELECT ip INTO new_ip
         FROM ips 
         WHERE id = inp_id;

         IF new_ip IS NOT NULL THEN
            RETURN new_ip;
         END IF; 

         /* see if the lowest IP address is free */
         IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ips 
                        WHERE ip = min_ip)
         THEN
            /* attempt to insert the new row */
            INSERT INTO ips (ip, id) 
            VALUES (min_ip, inp_id);

            /* return if that was successful */
            RETURN min_ip;
         END IF;    
         /* else, get the lowest IP address gap in "ips" */
         SELECT ip + 1 INTO new_ip
         FROM (SELECT ip,
                      CASE WHEN lead(ip) OVER (ORDER BY ip) = ip + 1
                           THEN FALSE
                           ELSE TRUE
                      END AS followed_by_gap
               FROM ips) subq
         WHERE followed_by_gap
         ORDER BY ip
         LIMIT 1;

         /* must not exceed maximum */
         IF new_ip > max_ip THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'no free IP address found';
         END IF;
         /* if the table is still empty, use the minimum */
         IF new_ip IS NULL THEN
            new_ip := min_ip;
         END IF;

         /* attempt to insert the new row */
         INSERT INTO ips (ip, id)
         VALUES (new_ip, inp_id);

         /* return if that was successful */
         RETURN new_ip;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN unique_violation THEN
            /* retry in another loop execution */
            NULL;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

Even if you don't like my approach, you can see what I mean with using a loop.

Comment: I've already got the unique constraint. Don't know how to rerun the function in case of failure in INSERT?

Comment: ...and any suggestion in a simpler approach is also something I would love to see.

Comment: You can call the function again in case of an error, or you can write a loop and a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ... END` block into the function.

Comment: I have added my version of the function. It came out longer that yours, but the query should be cheaper.

Comment: thx, seems your using inet2int instead of inet types? And the inet2int is missing?

Comment: Hmm, seems it doesn't select the lowest possible IP, but simply the next free IP. So  if `192.168.0.2` is taken, then the next free is `192.168.0.3` and not `192.168.0.1`?

Comment: My code uses `bigint` because that way I can easily calculate the "next" address by adding 1. The code should return the lowest free IP address; the first "gap" in the list.

Comment: Just tested the `SELECT ip + 1 INTO new_ip ...` isolated on a table `ips` with `192.168.0.3` inserted, and `192.168.0.0` as `min_ip` - that returned `192.168.0.4`, not `192.168.0.0` or `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. btw, it seems `inet` does support `+ 1` directly, as with `bigint` :)

Comment: Then my code can be greatly simplified. No conversion necessary.